# Creating an instance of class using lists and dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, class, object

I am working with classes and functions in python where I am facing some issues. I will explain step by step what I am trying to do:

1. I have a list of tasks to be accomplished. e.g:
   1:EAF Processing task for heat 1
   2:EAF Processing task for heat 2

Here, I have tried to create a id.e.g :

```
self.id=id
```

2. Each equipment is associated with list of equipment from the list of equipments.I have tried to implement it via :

```
equipment = ['EAF1','EAF2','AOD1', 'AOD2','LF1','LF2']
self.equipment=equipment
```

3. Each id(task) will have the processing time.e.g:
   {"1" :80.0
   "2" :40.0}
   I am unsure how to implement such logic?
4. Each task will have electricity consumption. e.g:
   {"1" :34.0
   "2" :49.0}

I have tried to implement the class like:

```
class Tasks():
    def __init__(self,equipment,id,**kwargs,processingtime,electricityconsumption):
        self.equipment=equipment
        self.id=id
        for key,value in kwargs.iteritems():
            setattr(self,key,value)
        self.processingtime=processingtime
        self.electricityconsumtption=electricityconsumption
```

However, I am not completely convinced and it throws an error.

It would be great if someone helps me in creating this logic of the class object.

I tried to create the instance of class using available data. But however I am somehow not able to interpret the definition of the object and did not know how to create the instances using these data.

Comment: There shouldn't be any arguments after `**kwargs`, it should be the last argument. Also why are you even using it there? You already seem to be taking all the arguments you say you need to store.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, Yes correct. I have processing times & electricity consumption as a dictionary. Can I use them as the instances?

Comment: Just pass the correct value in while instantiating `Tasks`? You shouldn't pass the entire dictionary in, given that it has information about the other tasks too.

Comment: [When you create a new `Tasks` object] how are you calling `Tasks`? You can just have *`def __init__(self,equipment,id,**kwargs)`* and call it like `Tasks(some_equipment, some_id, attr_x=value_x, processingtime={"1" :80.0 "2" :40.0}, electricityconsumption={"1" :34.0 "2" :49.0})` and so on and it'll do what I think you want it to [you'll no longer need the last 2 lines in *`__init__`*]

Comment: @Driftr95, I have different processing times & electricity consumption for each id. How do I call that?

Comment: Make the object using the values from your dictionary using `Task(equipment, id, processingTimeDictionary.get(i), electricityConsumptionDictionary.get(i))`.

Comment: @MargiShah I've added an answer based on my assumptions, but if that's not what you're going for, please clarify by including a sample of your current data and what data you would want one `Tasks` object to contain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *@Driftr95, I have different processing times & electricity consumption for each id. How do I call that?*

Not sure exactly what you're going for, but I'll suggest 2 solutions based on the assumption that your current data looks something like

```py
equipments = ['EAF1','EAF2','AOD1', 'AOD2','LF1','LF2']
procTimes = {"1": 80.0, "2": 40.0}
eleCon = {"1": 34.0, "2": 49.0}
```

---

#### Suggestion 1

If you just want to avoid the error, you can simply shift all arguments ahead of *`**kwargs`* as it should be.

```py
class Tasks():
    def __init__(self, equipment, id, processingtime:dict={}, electricityconsumption:dict={}, **kwargs):
        self.equipment = equipment
        self.id = id
        for key,value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self,key,value)
        self.processingtime = processingtime.get(id)
        self.electricityconsumtption = electricityconsumption.get(id)

tasksList = [
    Tasks(taskEq, str(taskId), procTimes, eleCon, kwarg1=f'kw1_{taskId}', kwarg2=f'kw2_{taskId}') 
    for taskId, taskEq in enumerate(equipments, 1)
]
```

[image: opkw]

---

#### Suggestion 2

```py
class Task():
    def __init__(self, id, equipment, **kwargs):
        self.id=id
        self.equipment=equipment
        for key,value in kwargs.items(): setattr(self,key,value)
```

<sup>I moved `id` ahead of `equipment` just because id is often the first parameter, but it doesn't really matter much.</sup>

Then you can produce a list (`tasksList`) of 6 `Task` objects with

```py
## Task(task_id,task_eq,processingtime=...,electricityconsumption=...) # <-- format
tasksList = [Task(
    str(taskId), taskEq, 
    processingtime=procTimes.get(str(taskId)), 
    electricityconsumption=eleCon.get(str(taskId))    
) for taskId, taskEq in enumerate(equipments, 1)]
```

[image: op]